# throw new TypeError or throw TypeError

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Typescript is there a difference in using new or not when throwing (TypeError)?

```
throw TypeError("some error here")
```

and

```
throw new TypeError("some error here")
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a JavaScript question than a TypeScript question. No, there's no difference in the technical result, both create new `TypeError` objects (details in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-nativeerror)). When called normally (not via `new`), both `Error` and the various "native" error constructors (`TypeError`, `ReferenceError`, etc.) will perform a `new` call (a *construct* call) instead of a normal call.

```js
const e1 = new TypeError("Error message here");
console.log(e1 instanceof TypeError); // true
console.log(e1.message);              // Error message here
const e2 = TypeError("Error message here");
console.log(e2 instanceof TypeError); // true
console.log(e2.message);              // Error message here
```

[Here's that same code on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgRhgXhmOB3GAVAngBzgFEAnEkEgCgCJTySYBbOCCAQwHM4YALOEuNQCUAbgBQAegkwZMAHoB+MaEggANnAB0akB0qIYAS0hQ2YYHBAAzHAWJkKomFJhQSAVzjLwEdVp16iJrMrJxwTrKRUc7SdBRMLOxcvPxeKtDwAEwotoRxVLQODCFJ3HwCwuIusoreqhrauvrZxtBmFta59vROLm6edb4NAc3BiWER0dEu+QmhyeVwQA), showing that TypeScript sees both `e1` and `e2` as being of type `TypeError`. The reason for that is that TypeScript's primary definition for `TypeError` (in `lib.es5.d.ts`) looks like this:

```typescript
interface TypeError extends Error {
}

interface TypeErrorConstructor extends ErrorConstructor {
    new(message?: string): TypeError;
    (message?: string): TypeError;
    readonly prototype: TypeError;
}

declare var TypeError: TypeErrorConstructor;
```

As you can see, it has both `new(message?: string): TypeError;` (constructor call returning `TypeError`) and `(message?: string): TypeError;` (normal call returning `TypeError`).

---

Subjectively, using `new` is clearer to readers of the code, highlighting that a new object is being created.